# WS2812B Reset time

Tags: ws2812, atmega

i am trying to implement the ws2812b with an atmega8,but i didn't understand a thing very well. if i pull low for >50 us, it says it resets, but what does that mean? it resets the current LED all data to 0 and latches the next data to the next led?

Comment: welcome, it helps if you add a reference to 'it' in 'it says', probably a datasheet of the WS2812B you are using (and add the page/fragment or copy it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "communication" reset.  You pull the data pin low for 50uS or more to start a new batch of communication.

It's illustrated in the datasheet here:
[image]

As you can see, between each batch of bits being sent the reset code is set. This is so that the first chip knows to start receiving again and not pass any data on until it's had all 24 of its bits.

Comment: so, the reset code needs to be sent between each 24 bits, right?

Comment: No. Between each 24 * NUM_LEDS bits.

Comment: aaah, got it, so it's for when the all the data is sent, so i can send new data again. thanks!

Comment: @SoxxZ_ Btw, it is sometimes used to stretch comunication. The data for single led are sent and then MCU can do something else for short time (as far as it's not longer than reset pulse).